# C++ instantiate class comparison

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

```cpp
class Myclass { 
public: 
    int value;
    Myclass(int a):value(a) {} 
};
```

Say I have a class declared and defined above. I'm trying to instantiate a `Myclass` instance.
Which of the following ways is the most efficient? 
(By "More efficient" I mean the code will execute faster.)

```cpp
Myclass c1(123);
Myclass c2=123;
Myclass c3{(123)};
Myclass c4{123}; // Is this called using "initialization list"?
```

Comment: They're probably identical on any reasonably modern compiler, you can test your code and see the generated assembly at http://godbolt.org

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong:

`Myclass c1(123)` is direct initialization, which should be the fastest.

`Myclass c1{123}` is also direct initialization in your case(not list initialization), and it should be as fast as the first one. Also that syntax was not availible prior to c++11.

`Myclass c1 = 123` is a copy initialization. It would first create a temporary `Myclass` object, then copy it to `c1`, so it would be slower than direct initialization. However, many modern compilers should be able to optimize that.

Not sure about `Myclass c1{(123)}`, but I believe it is equivalent to `Myclass c1{123}`